# Writing many files at once with Cordova / Phonegap 1.6.1 on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-io, cordova

When I write many files at once (batched or not) with an average size of 100KB, I get the following message in the output console:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate 
 (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) 
 failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. 
 main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

This is using the Cordova fileWriter: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter

What's the cause of this error and what's the best way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem. Found the cause, but no solution yet.

So far I've found that web view returns an error if a script runs for more than 10 seconds, stopping the user from interacting with the app. If you are using alert(), then the duration of the alertbox (until you press ok) may be counted in these 10 seconds.

Comment: It doesn't _seem_ to cause any problems to the user but I don't like errors in the output console :) I created an issue for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-562

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure about the implications of the error. I solved it by breaking up my long script and have it triggered by user interactions instead.